# New Activity not starting on click event?

Tags: java, android, navigation

I hope you are doing well, I ma having a problem, I am trying to clikc a button in my main activity and move to an other activity, but it is not working, I see that the layout changes but does not take me to where I want, it give me an empty screen, here is my MainActivity :

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @BindView(R.id.newContractBtn)
    Button newContractBtn;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ButterKnife.bind(this);

        newContractBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent newContractIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), NewContractActivity.class);
                MainActivity.this.startActivity(newContractIntent);
            }
        });

    }
}
```

Here is my NewContractActivity :

```
public class NewContractActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @BindView(R.id.newContractBtn)
    Button backToList;


    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState, @Nullable PersistableBundle persistentState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState, persistentState);
        setContentView(R.layout.new_contract);

        ButterKnife.bind(this);

        backToList.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                onBackPressed();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

The classes are both in the Android Manifest.xml.

here is the layout : ( 3 textviews and button - form )

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"

        >
        <RelativeLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            >
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="COSY"
                android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textSize="28sp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                />
            <Button android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:text="LIST" android:layout_alignParentRight="true" android:layout_marginRight="15dp"></Button>
        </RelativeLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="35dp"
        android:paddingLeft="20dp"
        android:paddingRight="20dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
    >
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="New Contract"
            android:textSize="22sp"
            >
        </TextView>
        <EditText

            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="Champ One"
            android:textSize="20sp">

        </EditText>

        <EditText

            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="Champ Two"
            android:textSize="20sp">

        </EditText>

        <EditText

            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:hint="Champ Three"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:textSize="20sp">

        </EditText>

        <TextView
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Success, Contract added, check your list now."
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textColor="@android:color/holo_green_dark"
            >
        </TextView>

        <TextView
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Error!"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textColor="@android:color/holo_red_dark"
            >
        </TextView>
        <Button android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp" android:textSize="18sp"  android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="SAVE">
        </Button>
        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/progressBar1"
            style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:indeterminate="true" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="You don't the right to add a contract, only a VENDEUR can do this."
            android:textSize="20sp"
            >
        </TextView>

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

I don't see the form as I said, I see and empty page.

Any help would be so much appreciated.

Comment: You've overridden the wrong `onCreate()` overload in `NewContractActivity`. You want the one without the `PersistableBundle` parameter, like you have it in `MainActivity`.

Comment: Yes, thanks, I did not know about that before because I am new to Android